# Andika fractions

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, pandoc

I have hand made the exercise with svg. See attachment. It was very cumbersome.

If I could write the étude in markdown and then do pandoc magic I could perhaps learn how to create a library of basic exercises. 
As simple as possible, but also as "schoolbook-like" as possible with Andika's open four, seven with a bar etc.

Below the markdown that I hope to learn how to tweak with more complex pandoc command line arguments than this:

```
~/lk$ pandoc --variable mainfont="Andika" lk-markdown-base-file.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o lk-md-xelatex-pdf.pdf
```

I copied that line from https://pandoc.org/demos.html, here's the markdown:

```
Andika fractions 0123456789

$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}·\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}·\frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}$

$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5}{5}·\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}·\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5}{10}+\frac{2}{10}=$

$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{6}{6}·\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{3}·\frac{1}{6}=\frac{6}{18}+$

$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}=\frac{7}{7}·\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4}{4}·\frac{1}{7}=$

$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{8}{8}·\frac{1}{5}+\frac{5}{5}·$

$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{9}{9}·\frac{1}{6}+$

$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{10}{10}·$

$\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{11}=$

$\frac{1}{9}+$
```

[image: Andika fractions made with svg]

If I could make such a fractions exercise with Andika without having to program svg, that would be fantastic!

Comment: Hi Jonas, the pdf with "Font Features for Andika" lists variants (e.g. "open four") of the numerals 1, 4, 6, 7 and 9, see bottom of page: https://software.sil.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2015/12/Andika-features5.000.pdf Best regards. //Erik

Comment: @ErikJosefsson I see, one has to generate it first for a quick preview https://scripts.sil.org/ttw/fonts2go.cgi

Comment: @JonasStein That link was new to me, and I did not know there were two variants of Andika. I have only installed (on debian)  `aptitude install fonts-sil-andika` without any particulars. I guess that if I have a pre-made font generated by the SIL-script site, I don't have to specify the which variant of the numerals I want to use?

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR:

You need to tell pandoc, which font to use in the YAML header:

```
---
mainfont: Andika
mainfontoptions: 
- CharacterVariant=1
- CharacterVariant=4
- CharacterVariant=6
- CharacterVariant=7

mathspec: true
mathfont: Andika
mathfontoptions: 
- CharacterVariant=1
- CharacterVariant=4
- CharacterVariant=6
- CharacterVariant=7
---

# Markdown below
```

---

> This works only for XeLaTeX. If you need a solution that works with LuaLaTeX see [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471958/29873).

The open digits can be activated by using the otf font features¹. You can do that with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[CharacterVariant={1,4,6,7}]{Andika}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
Andika fractions 0123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

Andika now works in text mode but not in math mode. To use Andika also in math mode you have to load `mathspec` instead of `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[CharacterVariant={1,4,6,7}]{Andika}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin)[CharacterVariant={1,4,6,7}]{Andika}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
Andika fractions 0123456789

\(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}\)

\(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5}{10}+\frac{2}{10}=\)

\(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{6}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{6}{18}+\)

\(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}=\frac{7}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{7}=\)

\(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{8}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{5}{5}\cdot\)

\(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{9}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\)

\(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{10}{10}\cdot\)

\(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{11}=\)

\(\frac{1}{9}+\)

\end{document}
```

To use this solution with `pandoc` you have to tell it to use `mathspec` and specify the main and math font with the option above. You can do that in the YAML header²:

```
---
mainfont: Andika
mainfontoptions: 
- CharacterVariant=1
- CharacterVariant=4
- CharacterVariant=6
- CharacterVariant=7

mathspec: true
mathfont: Andika
mathfontoptions: 
- CharacterVariant=1
- CharacterVariant=4
- CharacterVariant=6
- CharacterVariant=7
---

Andika fractions 0123456789

$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}$

$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5}{10}+\frac{2}{10}=$

$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{6}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{6}{18}+$

$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{7}=\frac{7}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{4}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{7}=$

$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{8}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{5}{5}\cdot$

$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{9}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+$

$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{10}{10}\cdot$

$\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{11}=$

$\frac{1}{9}+$
```

You can call pandoc now as usual:

```
$ pandoc input.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o output.pdf
```

[image]
–––

1. You can use `otfinfo -f Andika-R.ttf` to list all available font features.
2. Multiple option values can be set with a [simple YAML sequence](http://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/YAML).

Comment: Wow! I have spent days trying to make this happen on my own!! Is it possible to have all CharacterVariants active (i.e. 1, 4, 6, 7 and 9)? I tried to list with  comma separation, but this did not work: CharacterVariant=4,7

Comment: @ErikJosefsson If you want to have more than one feature activated, you need to put curly braces around them: `CharacterVariant={4,7}`

Comment: Sorry, didn't work with curly braces {4,7} in the YAML header:
   ---
   mainfont: Andika
   mainfontoptions: CharacterVariant={4,7}
   
   mathspec: true 
   mathfont: Andika
   mathfontoptions: CharacterVariant={4,7}
   ---

This is what pandoc said:


   Error producing PDF.
   ! Missing number, treated as zero.
   <to be read again> 
                      \protect 
   l.21   \ifxetex



I think I have all of Andika installed since I made the svg with font-feature-settings: "dig1" 1, "dig4" 1, "dg69" 1, "dig7" 1;
Almost there! :-) 
Thanks!!

Comment: You are right. Doesn't work that way. You have to use a YAML sequence. See edit.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that works with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, while using the non-default variants of the numerals `1`, `4`, `6`, `7`, and `9`. In addition, it employs an `array` environment, to help align all fraction terms, `+` symbols, and `=` symbols horizontally as well as vertically.

Observe that since Andika is a text font, not a math font, only the numerals in the math terms employ Andika; all other glyphs (such as `+` and `=`) are rendered using Latin Modern Math.

The code below actually presents two solutions, rather than just one solution. The first uses display-style math, while the secod uses text-style math. The difference is most readily apparent in the size of the `\frac` terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}       % column type for = and + operators
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\displaystyle}c}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Andika}[CharacterVariant={1,4,6,7}]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Andika}[range=up/{num},
                     CharacterVariant={1,4,6,7}]


\begin{document}
Andika numerals 0123456789

Solution 1: display-style math and fractions
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{8}{HC}H}
\frac{1}{1} &+&\frac{1}{4} &=& \frac{4}{4} &\cdot& \frac{1}{1} &+&
   \frac{1}{1} &\cdot& \frac{1}{4} &=& \frac{4}{4} &+&\frac{1}{4} &=& 
   \frac{5}{4}\\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{2} &+&\frac{1}{5} &=& \frac{5}{5} &\cdot& \frac{1}{2} &+&
   \frac{2}{2} &\cdot& \frac{1}{5} &=& \frac{5}{10} &+&\frac{2}{10}&=& 
   \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{3} &+&\frac{1}{6} &=& \frac{6}{6} &\cdot& \frac{1}{3} &+&
   \frac{3}{3} &\cdot& \frac{1}{6} &=& \frac{6}{18} &+&\\ 
   \addlinespace
\frac{1}{4} &+&\frac{1}{7} &=& \frac{7}{7} &\cdot& \frac{1}{4} &+&
   \frac{4}{4} &\cdot& \frac{1}{7} &=& \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{5} &+&\frac{1}{8} &=& \frac{8}{8} &\cdot& \frac{1}{5} &+&
   \frac{5}{5} &\cdot& \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{6} &+&\frac{1}{9} &=& \frac{9}{9} &\cdot& \frac{1}{6} &+&
   \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{7} &+&\frac{1}{10} &=&  \frac{10}{10} &\cdot& 
   \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{8} &+&\frac{1}{11} &=& \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{9} &+&\\ 
\end{array}
\]


Solution 2: text-style math and fractions
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{8}{cC}c}
\frac{1}{1} &+&\frac{1}{4} &=& \frac{4}{4} &\cdot& \frac{1}{1} &+&
   \frac{1}{1} &\cdot& \frac{1}{4} &=& \frac{4}{4} &+&\frac{1}{4} &=& 
   \frac{5}{4}\\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{2} &+&\frac{1}{5} &=& \frac{5}{5} &\cdot& \frac{1}{2} &+&
   \frac{2}{2} &\cdot& \frac{1}{5} &=& \frac{5}{10} &+&\frac{2}{10}&=& 
   \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{3} &+&\frac{1}{6} &=& \frac{6}{6} &\cdot& \frac{1}{3} &+&
   \frac{3}{3} &\cdot& \frac{1}{6} &=& \frac{6}{18} &+&\\ 
   \addlinespace
\frac{1}{4} &+&\frac{1}{7} &=& \frac{7}{7} &\cdot& \frac{1}{4} &+&
   \frac{4}{4} &\cdot& \frac{1}{7} &=& \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{5} &+&\frac{1}{8} &=& \frac{8}{8} &\cdot& \frac{1}{5} &+&
   \frac{5}{5} &\cdot& \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{6} &+&\frac{1}{9} &=& \frac{9}{9} &\cdot& \frac{1}{6} &+&
   \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{7} &+&\frac{1}{10} &=&  \frac{10}{10} &\cdot& 
   \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{8} &+&\frac{1}{11} &=& \\ \addlinespace
\frac{1}{9} &+&\\ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very helpful and useful and fantastic! You also helped solve how to send more than one CharacterVariant through pandoc's YAML

`code`
---
mainfont: Andika
mainfontoptions: [CharacterVariant=1, CharacterVariant=4, CharacterVariant=6, CharacterVariant=7]

mathspec: true
mathfont: Andika
mathfontoptions: [CharacterVariant=1, CharacterVariant=4, CharacterVariant=6, CharacterVariant=7]
---
`code`

I'll try to unwrap the snippet {C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} to see if I can reproduce that level of precision myself:

`code`
\begin{array}{*{8}{HC}H}
`code`

 Again, thank you!

//Erik